# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series"

Tags: python

I have the following code where I am downloading image files from a list of URLs in a data frame, but I am getting the following exception:
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series`

I have tried casting the data type to an `str` using `df.filename.astype(str)`, but it seems I am missing something else.

My code:

```py
import requests

image_url = [data.receipt]
username = xxx
password = 1111

for img in image_url:
    file_name = df.filename
    print("Downloading file:%s" % file_name)

    rq = requests.get(img, stream=True)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in rq:
            f.write(chunk)
            # f.print(chunk)
```

Output:

```
0    id_2020_a001
1    id_2020_a002
Name: filename, dtype: object
Downloading file:0    id_2020_a001
1    id_2020_a002
Name: filename, dtype: object
No connection adapters were found for '0    https://server.provide.com/api/v2/fo...\n1    https://server.provider.com/api/v2/fo...\nName: receipt, dtype: object'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Traceback:

```
<ipython-input-48-d1bd1bfdf9b0> in <module>()
     51  rq =  pull_data(img, form['username'], form['password'])
---> 52  with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
     54     for chunk in rq:
     55        f.write(chunk)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error in your post.

Comment: `df.filename` is a Pandas Series

Comment: `df.filename` is ***the whole*** `'filename'` column. You probably want to iterate over it... Anyway it's hard to say exactly how to fix without a [mre] and the full error traceback

Comment: check latest update.